# NOT working .net core 2.0 log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net-appender

I copied appender config section with "log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender" type from previous .net 4.5.2 project to current .net core 2.0 one. It seems not working at all.

And I'm sure that my config section is correct.

Is any know how to make it work? let the log4net could store log information into database?

Answer (score 3):

This appender is not supported yet. Check [supported appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html#Appenders)
Look at NLog.Web.AspNetCore which support writing to database.